# How to add atributes on pic stored from database

Tags: php, html, css

I want to know how to add picture attributes in php file that shows pictures from database..

In my php file I have this code to show my pictures.

```
 echo "<img src=pictures/".$row['picture'].">";
```

I want to add some attributes to them, I tried this but didnt work:

```
 echo <div class="piceffects">"<img src=pictures/".$row['picture'].">"</div>;
```

The "piceffects", are some attributes added in my CSS file
so how exactly I add that attributes in my pictures? :/

Comment: [**Got a parse error, didn't you?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Try this:
`echo "<div class='piceffects'><img src='pictures/".$row['picture']."'></div>";`

Comment: @BastianW bro x) THANK YOU! :D now it's so cool :D, put ur answer in the correct way, i have to mark it as my answer :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- indeed, i get some errors like you said but i just use: ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something went wrong with your quotes. Here is the correct way to put them:

```
 echo "<div class='piceffects'><img src='pictures/".$row['picture']."'></div>";
```

Comment: yes, you're right, i just fixed it 5 mins ago :)
thank you too for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the attributes specified in the `.piceffects` css class you'll have to make change the following in your css file

FROM

```
.piceffects {
}
```

TO

```
.piceffects img {
}
```

adding the `img` attribute in the css will make it apply to the images. Hope this helps

Comment: hmm, i'll keep that in mind, actually Bastian's answer was correct, the problem was in my code with the " in the wrong place..anyway thank you too for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTML within the PHP tages. You can do either of the two solutions:

```
echo "<div class='piceffects'><img src=pictures/".$row['picture']."></div>";
```

Or:

```
<div class="piceffects"><img src=pictures/"<? echo $row['picture'] ?>"></div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering! i found the solution some mins ago, i tried these 2 suggestions too, but none worked..i dont know about the second one, but in the first, you have forgot quotes in img src..it should be like this to work:

     <img src='pictures/".$row['picture']."'>